# Add Buttons in component DateRangePicker of Material-UI or customize DateRangePicker

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux, material-ui

Good day to everyone.
I encountered the problem of customization of the [DateRangePicker](https://next.material-ui.com/ru/components/date-range-picker/)  component from the `@material-ui` library. In particular, I'm trying to add 3 buttons `Button` under the calendar. That's how I came out now (image 1).
I already swore all the documentation and I miss knowledge to cope with this task. Please tell me how it can be done, at least words. I went to a deschanted way to add these buttons to the native (not controlled react) in the way, but I ran into a problem that I cannot suspend event handlers to start a REACT-REDUX ecosystem. I understand that the appeal to the elements should be done through the `ref`, but I don't even know how to get a DataPicker calendar component.

Image 1. [image]

As I did at the moment - it's horror. I make marking when opening the calendar `onopen`, which does not allow me to further attach an event differential and interact with local states (or at least with Dispatch).

```
<Grid item lg={3} md={5} sm={12}>
                    <MuiDateRangePicker
                        startText="От"
                        endText="До"
                        mask="__.__.____"
                        calendars={1}
                        value={selectedDate}

                        okText={"Okk"}
                        showDaysOutsideCurrentMonth={true}
                        showTodayButton={true}
                        showToolbar={false}
                        todayText={"Сегодня!"}
                        PopperProps={{id:'filter-data-range-picker', ref: calendarPopupRef}}
                        onOpen={() => {
                            console.log(`ff `,calendarPopupRef.current);
                            let calendarWrapper = calendarPopupRef?.current?.querySelector('.MuiPickersDesktopDateRangeCalendar-rangeCalendarContainer');
                            let panel = calendarWrapper?.querySelector('.calendar-bottom-panel');
                            if (!panel) {
                                let div = document.createElement('div');
                                div.innerHTML = `
                                    <div class="calendar-bottom-panel" style="display: grid; grid-gap: 10px; grid-template-columns: auto auto auto; padding: 0 14px 14px">
                                        <button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiButton-root MuiButton-outlined MuiButton-outlinedSizeSmall MuiButton-sizeSmall" tabindex="0" type="button" onClick=""><span class="MuiButton-label">День</span><span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span></button>
                                        <button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiButton-root MuiButton-outlined MuiButton-outlinedSizeSmall MuiButton-sizeSmall" tabindex="0" type="button" onClick=""><span class="MuiButton-label">Неделя</span><span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span></button>
                                        <button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiButton-root MuiButton-outlined MuiButton-outlinedSizeSmall MuiButton-sizeSmall" tabindex="0" type="button" onClick=""><span class="MuiButton-label">Месяц</span><span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span></button>
                                    </div>
                                `;
                                calendarWrapper?.appendChild(div);
                            }
                            
                        }}
                        onClose={() => console.log('close calendar')}

                        onChange={date => {
                            handleDateChange(date);
                            dispatch(changeValueFilterByKeyNameOfTreeAction("lastConversationTime", date as any))
                        }}

                        ToolbarComponent={(props) => (
                            <div {...props}>
                                
                                Test
                            </div>
                        )}
                        
                        
                        renderInput={(startProps, endProps) => (
                            <>
                                
                                <TextField 
                                    {...startProps} 
                                    variant="filled" 
                                    helperText=""
                                    inputProps={{...startProps.inputProps, placeholder:"дд.мм.гггг"}}
                                    InputProps={{
                                        endAdornment: (
                                            <InputAdornment position="end">
                                                {selectedDate[0] !== null && (
                                                    <IconButton size="small" onClick={() => {
                                                        const date = [null, selectedDate[1]]
                                                        handleDateChange(date)
                                                        dispatch(changeValueFilterByKeyNameOfTreeAction("lastConversationTime", date as any))
                                                    }}>
                                                        <ClearIcon fontSize="small"/>
                                                    </IconButton>
                                                )}
                                                <DateRangeIcon fontSize="small" />
                                            </InputAdornment>
                                        ),
                                    }}
                                />

                                
                            
                                <TextField 
                                    {...endProps} 
                                    variant="filled" 
                                    helperText=""
                                    inputProps={{...endProps.inputProps, placeholder:"дд.мм.гггг"}}
                                    InputProps={{
                                        endAdornment: (
                                            <InputAdornment position="end">
                                                {selectedDate[1] !== null && (
                                                    <IconButton size="small" onClick={() => {
                                                        const date = [selectedDate[0], null]
                                                        handleDateChange(date)
                                                        dispatch(changeValueFilterByKeyNameOfTreeAction("lastConversationTime", date as any))
                                                    }}>
                                                        <ClearIcon fontSize="small"/>
                                                    </IconButton>
                                                )}
                                                <DateRangeIcon fontSize="small" />
                                            </InputAdornment>
                                        ),
                                    }}
                                />
                                
                            </>
                        
                        )}
                    />
                </Grid>
```

Comment: Default material-ui's datepicker is definitely not that customizable. I'd assume you switch to something more suitable. Like `react-dates` https://github.com/airbnb/react-dates for example. At least I went that way and for good.

Comment: @aleksxor Thank you for advised. I looked carefully the library and it allows you to implement the bottom panel, as I need. I have a small question: is it possible to customize this library under Material-UI?

Comment: It doesn't use material-ui's components unfortunately. Though it's deeply customizable and you can make it look like your other components with much less effort.